# Replicating the UIDatePicker Font Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uipickerview, uidatepicker

i'm trying to replicate the exact font size used in `UIDatePicker` for a custom `UIPickerView`. Unfortunately I'm not able to get the correct font size.

What I've tried:

Swizzling the `setFont:` method of `UILabel` to print out the font when being a subclass of a `UIDatePickerView`

```
-(void) swizzledSetFont:(UIFont*)font{
    if([self view:self hasSuperviewOfClass:[UIDatePicker class]] ||
       [self view:self hasSuperviewOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIDatePickerWeekMonthDayView")] ||
       [self view:self hasSuperviewOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIDatePickerContentView")]){
       NSLog(@"Label:%@ Font:%@",self,font);
       [self swizzledSetFont:font];

    } else {
        //Carry on with the default
        [self swizzledSetFont:font];
    }
}
```

The same code works for swizzling the font color inside these labels, so thats not the problem.

This returns the following: `<UICTFont: 0x7f9f23cea230> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 21.00pt`

But setting this as the font of UILabels inside the custom `UIPickerView` does not yield the desired look.

Any Ideas? I think there might be some kind of `CALayer` stuff going on here, but I'm out of ideas on how to debug this. It's iOS 8 btw.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Alright wasn't aware of that, thanks for pointing it out/editing it.

Answer (score 1):

If your only purpose is just to know the font that UIDatePicker uses, using view debugger will simplify this lot more. Add a simple UIDatePicker to your view hierarchy and run it on your simulator. Then, debug the view and drill down the view hierarchy to find the font. I think this is lot more fun and simpler than what you have been doing.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know its possible to do it that way, still as seen in your video the returned font would be HelveticaNeue-Regular of Size 21pt. Try returning text with this font in a UIPickerView (for example in 
- pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent: ) and you'll see that its not the same size and or look.

Comment: Then run on your device and then inspect all the label. Do you think that view debugger shows different font that it actually use on device ?

Comment: That's my whole point yes, I was kind of surprised as well. I was just guessing that it might be because of some transforms on the Layer of the UIDatePicker, but there might be another explanation.